# Is there a way in .NET Framework to implement AAD authentication by MSAL.net?

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I have a project developed by ASP.net **MVC5** and the .NET Framework version is 4.7 and I have been implemented **AAD** authentication by **OWIN** **OpenID** Connect **Middleware**. It's working well. But in recent days I am studying **MSAL.net** and it helps us to do the same process in an easier way, every demo was developed in ASP.net Core, please help me that is there a way in .NET Framework to implement **AAD** authentication by **MSAL.net**?

Thanks!

Comment: I am also stuck with the same question. Are you able to implement MSAL in .net framework?

Comment: not really, I am trying to use SAML2